# Why is DocuSign is returning 504 Gateway Time-out?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I implemented DocuSign in my application and I'm currently using the developers account (free version).

After I click on finish signing, it keeps loading and eventually return 504 Gateway Time-out. It was working alright before, it redirects back to the frontend page but now I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use fiddler or some other tool, I don't think the 504 comes from DocuSign. After you finish signing it redirects to whatever URL you told DocuSign to go. It looks like it's DocuSign, but the 504 comes from that URL
(the browser shows DocuSign UI, and shows 504, the 504 is DocuSign attempting to redirect the browser to some other URL, that URL gives the error, not DocuSign)

Comment: You are very right, the error wasn't coming from Docusign. The endpoint I was calling to upload the signed document to Azure failed. Thanks